# Substr all value in Array

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I want to make substr on each value in my array, but it failed. I just can make the substr work when I tried to make some looping inside my array and then substr one by one on my value.
But it's not that I want

I have an array:

```
Array ( [0] => 41136.07.6 [1] => 21511.01.1 )
```

Expected output:

```
Array ( [0] => 41136 [1] => 21511 )
```

So far, I just do it with like this:

```
$temp = $this->input->post('account');
for ($count=0; $count < count($temp); $count++) {
    $accounttemp=substr($temp[$count], 0, 5);

    # code...
}
```

Is it possible or is there any function that makes my array change directly without I'm doing looping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map()` to achieve what you want.

```
$array = ['41136.07.6', '21511.01.1'];

$output = array_map(function($val) {
    return substr($val, 0, 5);
}, $array);

print_r($output);
```

See the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` loop, adding an `&` to the value parameter to allow it to be changed in the loop. For example:

```
$temp = array('41136.07.6', '21511.01.1');

foreach ($temp as &$accountnum) {
    $accountnum = substr($accountnum, 0, 5);
    // do some other stuff
}
print_r($temp);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 41136
    [1] => 21511
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Nhr30)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk`

```
$arr = ['41136.07.6', '21511.01.1'];

function substr05(&$item) {
   $item = substr($item, 0, 5);
}

array_walk($arr, "substr05");

print_r($arr);
# Array
# (
#    [0] => 41136
#    [1] => 21511
# )
```

[Online Verification](https://3v4l.org/TIaeb)